# Cloud Functions, when to clean temp disk?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

(Cloud functions video) They suggested to be careful about using global variables and temporary disks in cloud functions.

I can understand about global variables stuff.

but what about temp disks? When memory is allocated and accumulated on the temp disk, and how do I free it up?

Answer (score 0):

The `/tmp` directory is a RAM disk, so every file you keep in there eats up an amount of RAM equivalent to at least the size of that file. There's probably some overhead too, but I never checked.

The `/tmp` directory will be empty when the container boots, so you don't have to do anything for that.

Aside from that, you'll want to clean up temporary files that you create explicitly when you are done with them. But if you use the `/tmp` directory for caching frequently used results, you probably don't ever want to clean them up.

You could implement your own LRU caching policy on the `/tmp` files of course, but it seems a bit over the top for a serverless backend..

Comment: hi Frank, thanks for that infromation but I want to listen more like in low-level examples. I am using Cloud Function for Cloud Firestore Trigger and PushNotification. What is the tmp accumulation that can occur at this time? And what command do you use to delete allocated tmp memory?

Answer (score 0):

`/tmp` is accessed like you would with any file system read/write. This allows users to access the location path like they would on the system, it handles files and other object data like you would typically assume.

You can in practice clear it with `fs.rmdir();`.

- Use with care.